# How to detect if a PHP script is killed because it takes too long

Tags: php, apache, logging

I suspect that some scripts in my PHP application take too long to process and are killed after `max_execution_time`. I have learned how to modify the code to tackle that (with `register_shutdown_function`) but before modifying the code and because it's a bit hard to reproduce I want to be sure that this is the case.

I haven't found anything in the Apache or PHP log so I was wondering if I should configure something in PHP to log that or what to look for in the logs.

Comment: I think this shows up in the error log.  I'm not sure what you consider a code modification, but you can adjust it either in the php.ini file, or the .htaccess file without technically changing the code.  The default is 30 seconds.

Comment: I was able to trigger the error and be sure that the `PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time` is present in the logs in such cases. It was interesting to dig in the problem but I think that this is not the cause of my problem (because such logs don't correlate with the symptoms).

Answer (score 1):

Try comparing the start and end timestamps from the following script:

```
<?php

// SET TIMEOUT TIME
ini_set('max_execution_time', 10);

// SHUTDOWN CALLBACK
function shutdown(){

    // LOG END
    error_log("END: ".time());
}

// SET SHUTDOWN CALLBACK
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

// LOG START
error_log("START: ".time());

// INFINITE LOOP
while(true){

    // CONTINUE
    continue;

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea but it means modifying the code and being able to reproduce the problem which is not straightforward (it depends on the server load, the parameters passed to the script, etc.). I would prefer to detect that in the log.

Comment: @MathieuDubois You could check the PHP `error_log` and see if there are any timeouts from running PHP scripts. I am pretty sure if a script times out there will be a log that shows up there.

Comment: and possibly the fpm error logs if that is in your stack.

Comment: As I havre tried to mention, I have checked that on our production server but found nothing. It runs an antiquated version of PHP so maybe there is something here. I will try to trigger such errors with a simpler script to track it in the logs.

Comment: @MathieuDubois Maybe check your `php.ini` file to see what you have configured for the `log_errors` and `error_log` properties.

Comment: Well, the `PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time` is present in the logs. In fact I think that this is not the cause of my problem.